# mongoose geojson in schema, "Can't extract geo keys" error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I have a mongodb collection with a defined schema, and I updated this schema to include lat/lon coordinates.

old version:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    address: String,
    city: String,
    zip: String,
    country: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    mobile: String,
    website: String,
    email: String,
});
```

new version

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    address: String,
    city: String,
    zip: String,
    country: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    mobile: String,
    website: String,
    email: String,
    location: GeoJSON.Point
});

schema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
```

`GEOJSON.Point` comes from `mongoose-geojson-schema` and looks like this:

```
GeoJSON.Point = {
  'type'     : { type: String, default: "Point" },
  coordinates: [
    {type: "Number"}
  ]
}
```

The collection already contained data before I added the `location` property.

Apparently what happens now is that for some reason mongodb uses `{ coordinates: [], type: "Point" }` as default value for the existing documents, and I get errors like these:

```
 MongoError: Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5637ea3ca5b2613f37d826f6'), ...
 Point must only contain numeric elements
```

I have looked at how to specify a default value in a schema, but I see no way of setting the value to `null` in case of a GeoJSON.Point data type.

I also tried

```
db.collection.update({},{$set:{location:null},{multi:true})
```

but that didn't seem to help either.

Is it because of the index on the `location`?

Comment: The Mongoose 3.6 [release notes](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#geojson-support-mongodb--24) suggest that you should use arrays-of-Numbers as type. Where's `GeoJSON.Point` coming from?

Comment: I edited my question with that extra info

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to upgrade `GeoJSON.Point` to a [sub document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) with a proper schema:

```
GeoJSON.Point = new mongoose.Schema({
  'type'     : { type: String, default: "Point" },
  coordinates: [ { type: "Number" } ]
});
```

Combined with the [`minimize`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#minimize) option, which it enabled by default, this will make Mongoose only save the `location` property if it is actually set.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to not use `GeoJSON.Point` as a schema type. Just use mixed object type and everything will work properly.

```
location: Schema.Types.Mixed
```